# MotoG 1st gen xt1032 unlocked not rooted phone stuck at startup logo screen

Tags: boot-loop, motorola-moto-g

I have a moto g 1st gen unlocked xt1032 phone that's stuck on the startup logo screen. It's running kitkat 4.4.4

It won't go past that, just stays on.

I turned it on one day and it just started doing that. It's network unlocked but probably not rooted, and probably had adb debugging enabled. I really want it working as before if possible, but even if I can just access the data to get the contacts in there, it would be a great thing.
I don't want to factory reset it until I can restore it back to normal or get the contacts info.

(is this what's known as a bootloop issue?)

Thanks in advance